# Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. SP Provider hosted

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, ssl

im trying to configure my sharepoint server to rung sharepoint provider hosted apps.
i followed this article on msdn to cinfigure the machine  and then configured IIS to run site  run over https. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901.aspx

and this this article to configure SSL
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2013/01/21/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

now i can can browse my sharepoint site on "ttps://myServername"

but when i try to deploy my provider hosted app to this site, i got this exception

```
       {"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust 
         relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."}

 innerException: 

       {"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."}
```

i can se that the certificate that i created to https on iis is uploaded to sharepoint-trust page.

the certificates are eved imoprted to MMC certificates, sharepoint and Trusted

what can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Provided Hosted Apps with Self Signed Certificate are really difficult to nail down.

Hence we need to approach step by step.

First check whether App Domain is configured properly or not ? to check this try creating SharePoint Hosted Hello World App and check whether it is loading or not.

If SharePoint Hosted App is working fine then it means that something is missed out while creating Certificate.

Thanks